# how to arrange the <div> inline in a layout

Tags: html, css

I have read some of the similar questions posted and tried them in my code. I am still getting stuck.
Please see my code below. I need to arrange the main content and arrange the three smaller contents below it. I also need to arrange the footer at the bottom.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title> CSS Attempt </title>
     <style type="text/css">
#container {width: 960px; margin: 0 auto; background:#ffffff; border:1px solid black; height:500px;}
#header { background:#ffffff; height:60px;}
#navigation {width:960px;background:#555555;text-align:left; height:35px;}
#sidebar {width:170px; height: 300px; text-align: left; border-right: 5px solid grey; list-style: none; margin-top: 20px; margin-left: 20px; float:left;}
#content {width:750px; height:150px; background-color: #333333; margin-left:190px; float: right; margin-top:0px   }
#display {width: 220px;height:200px;background-color: #cccccc }
#center {width: 220px;height:200px; border:2px solid black }
#footer {width:960px;text-align:right; height:35px; float: right;}
 </style>
</head>


<body>
<div id="container">
        <div id="header">
        <p><img src="logo.png" alt = "Image not available"></p>
        </div>

    <div id="navigation">
    <p>Home</p>
    </div>
    <div id="sidebar">
    <p> Left Content </p>
    </div>
    <div id = "content">
    <p> Main Content </p>
    <div id = "display">
    <p> Content 1</p>
    </div>
    <div id = "center">
    <p> Central Content </p>
    </div>
    <div id = "display">
     <p> Content 2</p>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div id = "footer">
     <p> copyright </p>
    </div>

</div>  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: So, what goes wrong, what did you try, and why didn't the other answer you found help you?

Comment: I tried using "overflow" and "display:inline" for the main content but the divs just happen to come one below another. I tried changing the arrangement of the divs as well.

Answer (score 2):

With the help of CSS3 flex box, we can have boxes next to each other with ease:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title> CSS Attempt </title>
     <style type="text/css">
#container {width: 960px; margin: 0 auto; background:#ffffff; border:1px solid black; height:500px;}
#header { background:#ffffff; height:60px;}
#navigation {width:960px;background:#555555;text-align:left; height:35px;}
#sidebar {width:170px; height: 300px; text-align: left; border-right: 5px solid grey; list-style: none; margin-top: 20px; margin-left: 20px; float:left;}
#content {width:750px; height:150px; background-color: #333333;margin: 20px 0 0 20px; float: right; }
#display {width: 220px;height:200px;background-color: #cccccc }
#center {width: 220px;height:200px; border:2px solid black }
#footer {width:960px;text-align:right; height:35px; float: right;}
.leftAndMain {display: flex;}
.mainInnerContents {display: flex;}
 </style>
</head>


<body>
<div id="container">
        <div id="header">
        <p><img src="logo.png" alt = "Image not available"></p>
        </div>

    <div id="navigation">
    <p>Home</p>
    </div>
<div class="leftAndMain">
    <div id="sidebar">
    <p> Left Content </p>
    </div>

    <div id = "content">
    <p> Main Content </p>
    <div class="mainInnerContents">
        <div id = "display">
        <p> Content 1</p>
        </div>
        <div id = "center">
        <p> Central Content </p>
        </div>
        <div id = "display">
         <p> Content 2</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    </div>
</div>
    <div id = "footer">
     <p> copyright </p>
    </div>

</div>  
</body>
</html>
```

I only add two divs surrounding other divs, one with `class="leftAndMain"` and another with `class="mainInnerContents"`.

I Also added two lines to `<style>` tag:

```
.leftAndMain {display: flex;}
.mainInnerContents {display: flex;}
```

and some minor changes in `#content`.

Comment: Ok thanks. I have never come across the flex property. I just need to edit the dimensions and i am set. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

There is a bug in your HTML. Two elements cannot have the same id, but you used `display` twice. I've now renamed the second one to `display2`, but I think you should consider using classes for styling instead.

Anyway. In the snippet below, the three blocks are displayed as table cells, so they are next to each other. The footer is 'cleared' so it is displayed below the left floated sidebar. The float of the content itself is removed, so it just is displayed adjacent to the side bar.

```css
/* Display the three block as cells, so they are next to each other. 
   You may specify a width for each of them. */
#display,
#center,
#display2 {
  display: table-cell;
}
#container {
  /* Removed float here. Content is just adjacent to side bar. */
  width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 500px;
}
#header {
  background: #ffffff;
  height: 60px;
}
#navigation {
  width: 960px;
  background: #555555;
  text-align: left;
  height: 35px;
}
#sidebar {
  width: 170px;
  height: 300px;
  text-align: left;
  border-right: 5px solid grey;
  list-style: none;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  float: left;
}
#content {
  height: 150px;
  background-color: #333333;
  margin-left: 190px;
  margin-top: 0px
}
#display {
  width: 220px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #cccccc
}
#center {
  width: 220px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 2px solid black
}
#footer {
  width: 960px;
  text-align: right;
  height: 35px;
  /* Clear to force the footer to the bottom. Add a border to show that this is working */
  border: 1px solid red;
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>CSS Attempt</title>
</head>


<body>
  <div id="container">
    <div id="header">
      <p>
        <img src="logo.png" alt="Image not available">
      </p>
    </div>

    <div id="navigation">
      <p>Home</p>
    </div>
    <div id="sidebar">
      <p>Left Content</p>
    </div>
    <div id="content">
      <p>Main Content</p>
      <div id="display">
        <p>Content 1</p>
      </div>
      <div id="center">
        <p>Central Content</p>
      </div>
      <div id="display2">
        <p>Content 2</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="footer">
      <p>copyright</p>
    </div>

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```